# Windows 10 Clean Install Failed and Stuck on a Boot Loop (No Administrator Account)

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, usb, hp-laptop

So, my son recently got a virus on my HP Windows 10 Home laptop. So what I did was backed up all the files that I need then I went into `Settings` -> `Recovery` -> `Reset this PC` -> `Remove Everything` and did a clean install.

It went smoothly until I got an infinite loop on a blue screen saying `Just a Moment...` it was stuck saying that for hours. So I went to Google on my other PC, searched for fixes and came across one saying to go into recovery mode and open command prompt.

I did that and it told me to run a command that opened the registry editor (regedit.exe) then it told me to go edit a value to I think `3` and after I edited that value my PC boots up then loads startup screen.

While loading the HP logo disappears then it just restarts and it repeats. So, what I did to try and fix this (it failed) was I went into recovery and did another clean install.

Then it got stuck at 2% for hours upon hours so I turned it off (even though it said not to) and now there's no administrator account on my PC because it didn't finish installing Windows. I can't use any of the recovery tools because it asks for an administrator account and there is none.

My PC is stuck at restarting over and over because Windows isn't installed. I've tried installing Windows with a USB drive (I downloaded the ISO and formatted the USB) but when I try to boot from the USB drive it does the EXACT same thing: my PC boots up then while on the loading startup screen and while loading the HP logo disappears, then it just restarts and it repeats.

How do I fix this? I don't want to buy a new laptop ;(

Comment: I'd suggest removing the _Urgent!_ from your title. No one is going to alter their course of action upon seeing that word and I think you'll find that it has the opposite effect of its intention.

Comment: @n8te thank you, I removed that from my title.

Comment: You should be able to access the HP Recovery Manager independent from Windows and it is installed on a recovery partition on your hard drive. It should be accessible by pressing F11 (on some models Esc + F11) when you first bootup your PC. See [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02638587)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring everything else and replying to your second last paragraph.

If you want to make a bootable USB Drive then simply formatting and copying installation files to it will not work. I suggest you use simple application like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to burn the ISO in USB Drive which then can be used to install fresh Windows.

After burning the ISO files to USB, insert it in your laptop and press `F9` after you press `Power button` of laptop to boot while the startup screen(or HP logo) is still on. Then choose your `USB Drive` for the boot media.

The fresh installation should go smoothly. (I'm not going to explain about `UEFI` or `Legacy boot` options but still shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. The problem is the laptop I'm using right now needs 8 gb of space to download the iso and this laptop was cheap and only came with 27 gb and most of that space is used with programs that came with the laptop... How could I safely remove default programs my laptop came with?

Comment: Also, I downloaded a smaller Windows 10 iso (3 GB) from a site and what I meant by formatting the usb is I used a tool. This is the tool I used: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485

Comment: And when I put the usb drive in the pc and press `F9` then it doesn't detect my iso

Comment: Instead of using any other medium I strongly recommend using [Rufus][https://rufus.akeo.ie/] instead. If you have trouble using it you can use [this guide][https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-almost-any-os/] to learn how to use it. Then I believe when you press `F9` it will detect your USB Drive.